# Please help I have 5 WPF Textbox and DataGrid, using Entity FrameWork

Tags: binding

I m experiencing problem when I try to updating UI form
this is my ADO.NET Entity FrameWork model Entity Products with Column
with the following columns

ProductID int PK,

ProductName nvarchar(50),

ProductCode nvarchar(50),

ProductType nvarchar(50),

Description nvarchar(50),

CreateDate DateTime

and ProductPrice money

and I have 5 TextBoxes which contain 
txtPName,txtDescription,txtCode,txtPrice,txtType,Datagrid to list all product from Database and btnupdate.and my textboxes are all binded correctly with datagrid, when I select any Item from the Datagrid it load the selectedItem to the all 5 txtboxes
so my problem started when I try to edit data from textboxes and click update button to update the the database.

this is my xaml code from UI

and xaml.cs for update button

```
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

{

```
        if (ProductList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            //get selected information first
            Product newProduct = new Product();
            newProduct.ProductName = txtName.Text.Trim();
            newProduct.ProductPrice = (decimal)(12.00);//decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            newProduct.ProductType = txtType.Text.Trim();
            newProduct.ProductCode = txtProductCode.Text.Trim();
            newProduct.Description = txtDescription.Text.Trim();
            newProduct.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;//
            Product product = ProductList.SelectedValue as Product;
            //col.Remove(product);
            //col.Add(newProduct);
            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Row is updated successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select");
        }
    }
```

the update code does not update the database.....
Please Guys I need help
from brianbk 
email kagisobk@gmail.com

Comment: Moderator flags send communication straight to the site moderators, and should be used to report issues that moderators need to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create a new instance to update an existing entity, just apply the edits to the edited object, Entity Framework will track any changes you do to entities and will update the DB as appropriate when calling SaveChanges().

So just get the selected object as you did then transfer the new values to its properties and finally you call SaveChanges:

```
Product product = ProductList.SelectedValue as Product;
product.ProductName = txtName.Text.Trim();
product.ProductPrice = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
....
db.SaveChanges();
```

But the recommended and more efficient approach that you should be using is to use Data Binding to let WPF transfer the data between your entity and controls in both directions (Load/Update).

then in update button you just need to call SaveChanges().

Comment: Thanks Mohammad but the query does not update to the database I think the must something wrong with my code because it only update Datagrid